# Estimating number of results in Google App Engine Query

Tags: algorithm, google-app-engine, random

I'm attempting to estimate the total amount of results for app engine queries that will return large amounts of results.

In order to do this, I assigned a random floating point number between 0 and 1 to every entity.  Then I executed the query for which I wanted to estimate the total results with the following 3 settings:

```
 * I ordered by the random numbers that I had assigned in ascending order
 * I set the offset to 1000
 * I fetched only one entity
```

I then plugged the entities's random value that I had assigned for this purpose into the following equation to estimate the total results (since I used 1000 as the offset above, the value of OFFSET would be 1000 in this case):

```
1 / RANDOM * OFFSET
```

The idea is that since each entity has a random number assigned to it, and I am sorting by that random number, the entity's random number assignment should be proportionate to the beginning and end of the results with respect to its offset (in this case, 1000).

The problem I am having is that the results I am getting are giving me low estimates.  And the estimates are lower, the lower the offset.  I had anticipated that the lower the offset that I used, the less accurate the estimate should be, but I thought that the margin of error would be both above and below the actual number of results.

Below is a chart demonstrating what I am talking about.  As you can see, the predictions get more consistent (accurate) as the offset increases from 1000 to 5000.  But then the predictions predictably follow a 4 part polynomial. (y = -5E-15x4 + 7E-10x3 - 3E-05x2 + 0.3781x + 51608).

Am I making a mistake here, or does the standard python random number generator not distribute numbers evenly enough for this purpose?

Thanks!

[image]

**Edit:**

It turns out that this problem is due to my mistake.  In another part of the program, I was grabbing entities from the beginning of the series, doing an operation, then re-assigning the random number.  This resulted in a denser distribution of random numbers towards the end.

I did a little more digging into this concept, fixed the problem, and tried it again on a different query (so the number of results are different from above).  I found that this idea can be used to estimate the total results for a query.  One thing of note is that the "error" is very similar for offsets that are close by.  When I did a scatter chart in excel, I expected the accuracy of the predictions at each offset to "cloud".  Meaning that offsets at the very begging would produce a larger, less dense cloud that would converge to a very tiny, dense could around the actual value as the offsets got larger.  This is not what happened as you can see below in the cart of how far off the predictions were at each offset.  Where I thought there would be a cloud of dots, there is a line instead.

[image]

This is a chart of the maximum after each offset.  For example the maximum error for any offset after 10000 was less than 1%:

[image]

Comment: Excellent question! I've pondered doing this myself. Have you tried this on a number of different datasets? Is it possible that it's just a fluke that this particular dataset tends to result in underestimations?

Comment: Hey Nick, I'm embarrassed to say, that I'm pretty sure the problem is that I had forgotten about another operation that I was doing that sorted by the random number and then modified entries from the beginning.  So basically I had made the "random" numbers less random.  I'm going to try and fix this soon and then see how accurate the results are.

Comment: Doh! Yes, that would probably explain it. And it's a good caveat for anyone using the same approach.

Comment: @Nick - Haha, yeah that's the kind of thing that happens when you start to get tired and dizzy and don't call it quits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick thought:

1. Have you tried Datastore Statistics API? It may provide a fast and accurate results if you won't update your entities set very frequently.
   http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/stats.html

   [EDIT1.]
2. I did some math things, I think the estimate method you purposed here, could be rephrased as an "Order statistic" problem.
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_order_statistics_of_the_uniform_distribution

For example:

If the actual entities number is 60000, the question equals to "what's the probability that your 1000th [2000th, 3000th, .... ] sample falling in the interval [l,u]; therefore, the estimated total entities number based on this sample, will have an acceptable error to 60000."

If the acceptable error is 5%, the interval [l, u] will be [0.015873015873015872, 0.017543859649122806]
I think the probability won't be very large.

Comment: I agree that the OP should look more into the stats behind this. Perhaps a posting to the math/stats SO would be appropriate - I'm sure the statisticians would have a better handle on how best to estimate number of results based on this data.

Answer (score 2):

When using GAE it makes a lot more sense not to try to do large amounts work on reads - it's built and optimized for very fast requests turnarounds. In this case it's actually more efficent to maintain a count of your results as and when you create the entities.

If you have a standard query, this is fairly easy - just use a [sharded counter](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) when creating the entities. You can seed this using a map reduce job to get the initial count.

If you have queries that might be dynamic, this is more difficult. If you know the range of possible queries that you might perform, you'd want to create a counter for each query that might run.

If the range of possible queries is infinite, you might want to think of aggregating counters or using them in more creative ways.

If you tell us the query you're trying to run, there might be someone who has a better idea.

Comment: This actually may not be the case here. Using this statistical sampling approach allows the OP to calculate estimated counts on a wide variety of queries, without knowing the queries he'll need ahead of time. Further, he can explicitly decide where the tradeoff between runtime and accuracy should be by setting the offset.

Comment: True enough... it is a very interesting problem. I remember that datastore team (don't know if you were on it) were doing something similar for cursors - there was a random number inserted into every entity, but it wasn't being exposed.

Comment: Yup, that's the 'scatter index'. It's available as `__scatter__`, and it's used for mapreduce. It's not on every entity, though, only every nth.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly deal with the calculations aspect of your question, but would using the `count` attribute of a query object work for you? Or have you tried that out and it's not suitable? As per the docs, it's only slightly faster than retrieving all of the data, but on the plus side it would give you the actual number of results.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_count

Comment: The problem with count is that it will eventually time out.  This seemed to happen around 300k results and above.  Also, when approaching that number, the queries last a long time, up to 30 seconds.

Comment: Fair enough. That's quite a large result set - are you doing this via a cron or mapreduce job? Again, not dealing with your question, but do you need to be pulling out so much at once? :)

Comment: I don't need to pull it out all at once.  Getting a good idea of the size of the result set is useful to me though.